# ASP.NET MVC Razor Content Placeholders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Perhaps this has been addressed somewhere else, but I can't find the keywords to search for.

In ASP.NET MVC with the Razor view engine: I have a view which renders with the same if statement repeated numerous times, in different parts of the html. I'm wondering if there's a way to consolidate all of these if's into a single if and set values for placeholders that would save the spot where each of those if's are, like so:

```
<div>@ph1</div>
<div>@ph3</div>
<div>@ph2</div>

@if(true)
{
    ph1 = "<div>adfad<div>"
    ph2 = "dsfaadfad"
    ph3 = Model.Value
}
```

This is kind of a stupid example, but I think it makes the point of what I mean.

Comment: You should have enough rep now to post your answer as an answer.  You should do so.

Comment: What message are you getting when you try to post it as answer?  10 rep is all that is required to remove the new user limitations that would prevent you from posting answer.  See http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
    MvcHtmlString ph1 = new MvcHtmlString("");
    MvcHtmlString ph2 = new MvcHtmlString("");
    if (true)
    {
        ph1 = new MvcHtmlString("<div>" + Model.Value + "<div>");
        ph2 = new MvcHtmlString("<div>fsgfdgdfg<div>");
    }
}

@ph1
@ph2
```

Again, silly usage, but it makes the point.

As was suggested in one of the answers, a nice addition to what I have is to assign a helper. This makes it easier to assign multiple statements without a lot of concatenation.

```
@helper helper()
{
    <span>@Model.Value</span>
    <div>dsfadsfasdfdfa</div>
}

@{
    MvcHtmlString ph1 = new MvcHtmlString("");
    MvcHtmlString ph2 = new MvcHtmlString("");
    if (true)
    {
        ph1 = new MvcHtmlString("<div>" + Model.Value + "<div>");
        ph2 = new MvcHtmlString(helper().ToHtmlString());
    }
}

@ph1
@ph2
```

If anybody has better ideas, I'd still be interested.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine.  You could also use a Razor Helper

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Views shouldn't normally have logic in your views (especially a single helper that is creating html).  A better option is to use partial views or display for templtates.

**models/[controller]**

```
public class SomeViewModel()
{
  //[UIHint("PhoneNumber")]
  //public string ph1 { get; set; }
  //[UIHint("PhoneNumber")]
  //public string ph1 { get; set; }
  //[UIHint("PhoneNumber")]
  //public string ph1 { get; set; }

  //if these all represent phone numbers, it would be ideal to
  [UIHint("PhoneNumbers")]
  IEnumerable<string> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

**views/[controllers]**

```
@model SomeViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PhoneNumbers);
```

**view/shared/DisplayTemplates/PhoneNumbers.cshtml**

```
@model IENumerable<string>

@foreach (string phoneNumber in Model)
{
  <div>@phoneNumber</div>
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem and I personally don't use DisplayFor because it's much easier and more natural to configure UI through HTML and keep UI stuff out of my data service.